# Magento2 - A simple custom API module

Tags: magento2, module, api

I have a problem when I create a new custom API module, my module is below:
[image]

**Content of : CalculatorInterface.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tohq\Webapi\Api;

interface CalculatorInterface
{
    public function cal($num1, $num2);
}
```

**Content of: Calculator.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tohq\Webapi\Model;
use Tohq\Webapi\Api\CalculatorInterface;


class Calculator implements CalculatorInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns total of two numbers
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $num1
     * @param int $num2
     * @return int $result
     */
    public function cal($num1, $num2)
    {
        // TODO: Implement cal() method.
        $result =  $num1 + $num2;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Content of webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/webapi/cal/:num1/:num2" method="GET">
        <service class="Tohq\Webapi\Api\CalculatorInterface" method="cal"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**Content of : di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Tohq\Webapi\Api\CalculatorInterface" type="Tohq\Webapi\Model\Calculator" />
</config>
```

============== My issue below ==============
When I call Rest api : magento2.dev/rest/V1/webapi/cal/3/5 
I got this issue:

> **This XML file does not appear to have any style information
>   associated with it. The document tree is shown below.**
>       
>       Class does not exist
>       `-1`
>       
>       0 D:\xampp\htdocs\srcDebug\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor.php(148):
>   ReflectionClass->__construct('') 1
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\srcDebug\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor.php(322):
>   Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->_createFromArray(NULL,
>   '3') 2
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\srcDebug\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor.php(119):
>   Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->convertValue('3',
>   NULL) 3
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\srcDebug\app\code\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver.php(101):
>   Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->process('Tohq\Webapi\Api...',
>   'cal', Array) 4
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\srcDebug\app\code\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest.php(299):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve() 5
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\srcDebug\app\code\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest.php(216):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest() 6
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\srcDebug\var\generation\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor.php(37):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>   7 D:\xampp\htdocs\srcDebug\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>   8 D:\xampp\htdocs\srcDebug\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() 
>   9
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\srcDebug\index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
>   10 {main}

**Anybody can see my issue and how to fix it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface needs to have the "annotation" `@param` and `@return` in your method. Can add `@api` at the first interface class or before method.

```
/**
*@api
*/
interface CalculatorInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns total of two numbers
     *
     * @param int $num1
     * @param int $num2
     * @return int $result
     */
     public function cal($num1, $num2);
}
```

Comment: @api can be ommited on the interface declaration, but added only on the function declarations.

Comment: it's mean: if we put '@api' on head of interface class, all public functions will use as api methods. Is that right?

Comment: Let's me check and confirm again.

Comment: Yes, all the public functions can be used as api methods.